# What is the behaviour of CSP if default-src not specified?

Tags: content-security-policy

Basically all in the title.

Imagine a simple CSP like

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self'
```

What is the behaviour of directives that would normally fall back to `default-src` which are not specified such as `img-src` or `frame-src`? Will they default to open (allow everything) or default to closed (allow nothing)?

Unless I'm missing it, neither

- [the Mozilla CSP docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/default-src), and
- [content-security-policy.com](https://content-security-policy.com/default-src/)

specify the behaviour if directives are missing.

Comment: allow everything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If no CSP is specified for a directive, it falls back to `default-src`.

If there is no `default-src` CSP, it does not fall back on any directive and thus it allows everything.

I have searched the [RFC](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/) about it and I could hardly find anything to quote that would push my statement. However, this is implied multiple times.

> To enforce a policy, the user agent MUST parse the policy and enforce
> each of the directives contained in the policy

`default-src` is a directive by itself. Thus, it WILL enforce `default-src` which actions is to set the default value for all others directive. If `default-src` the browser does not have to enforce any default restriction for other directives.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I suspected, but good to confirm.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the behaviour of directives that would normally fall back to
> default-src which are not specified such as img-src or frame-src? Will
> they default to open (allow everything) or default to closed (allow
> nothing)?

A distinction should be made between 2 situations:

1. directive is specified with empty list of sources, ex, `style-src ;`. Empty source list means '**as much restrictive as possible**", for the `style-src` it's equal to `style-src 'none';`
2. no directive specified at all. Common rule: if directive is not specified - it is **allowed everything** what's this directive controls.

But in the CSP was implemented a fallback mechanism for **some** directives, therefore those can be implicitly setted even not specified.
And here the devil hides in the details because those not always inites from default-src... Let's see your example below:

> Imagine a simple CSP like
>
> Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self'
>
> What is the behaviour of directives that would normally fall back to default-src

So we have the `worker-src` directive not specified and `default-src` too (means no restrictions if fallback). Are workers allowed from any sources o not?
The answer is:

- Edge browser: yes, all workers are allowed from any source
- other browsers: workers are allowed from 'self' only.

That's because a fallback performs more [complicated](https://csplite.com/csp62/#worker-src) way:
`worker-src` -> `child-src` -> `script-src` -> `default-src`.
So `worker-src` does fallback to `default-src` only if absent `child-src` and `script-src` (Edge erroneously skips script-src in this chain).

Hence we have an additional rule:

3. Fetch-directives do fallback if omitted, but `default-src` is a **final** fallback, and some directives has an [intermediate](https://csplite.com/csp62/#final_fallback) ones.

> 

The above is a theoretical part of CSP spec. Some devils also hides in a practice of realisation too. Therefore it is a rule 4:

4. Don't rely on initiation via `default-src` in complicated cases, it not always work [according to spec](https://csplite.com/csp/test253/#bug_FF_nonce-value_NOT_cancels_unsafe-inline_in_default-src). Do specify directives explicitly.